# Does TexPad support fontspec?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ipad, texpad

I am compiling a .tex file with XeTeX from the cloud on an Ipad with TexPad. Whenever I try to load the fontspec package, it fails. Does anyone have any experience with this problem? Can TexPad simply not be used with fontspec?

Comment: I would change your question title to the form of a question to make it more likely to come up in searches e.g. Does TeXPad support the fontspec package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2020

As of version 1.8.5,
`fontspec` is now supported by the local typesetter (`hyperref` too).

## Update June 30, 2016

YIKES! I spoke to soon. With such anticipation, I jumped the gun and realized that my document with `fontspec` was typesetting with the cloud typesetter. *Still waiting to say: "Texpad's local (on-device compiler) and cloud compiler both support `fontspec` and work great!"* Thanks to cfr and Joseph Wright for helping me notice this. **Only the cloud compiler supports fontspec.**

---

The developers claim to provide fontspec support starting with version 1.7. I have been waiting over 3 years for this.

#Update April 2, 2016

> Version 1.7 is currently in beta testing. We hope to release it in 2-3
> weeks. It includes a hugely improved typesetter with beamer, tikz and
> a host of other issues resolved. Fontspec (or support for local fonts
> in general) will follow later this summer.
>
> The app also delivers new UI that matches Texpad OS X and hence is a
> lot more productive on larger iPads.

> **Fontspec**

> XeTeX and LuaTeX both support unicode and TTF fonts natively through the fontspec package. This is in testing right now, and it will be available on both platforms from 1.7.

#Source
https://www.texpadapp.com/support/ios/typesetting/vvtex-support

#Release Notes
(as of this answer)

The past few updates, but still not v.1.7 from https://www.texpadapp.com/releasenotes/tpios:

```
Version 1.6.20
Misc. dropbox file access fixes
Version 1.6.19
Misc. file handling improvements
Backup manager for edited documents
64 bit support (updated OpenSSL)
Version 1.6.18
Dropbox error handling improved.
Dropbox move/copy bug fixed where multiple move/copy calls would occasionally fail.
Version 1.6.17
A fix for Dropbox uploads for cloud typeset PDFs
```

Comment: The question is about the local compiler, though, is it? I thought that was different.

Comment: @cfr I am referring to the local compiler ;)

Comment: Sorry. I meant that the question is not about the local compiler, is it?

Comment: Ah. Right. Well the cloud in this case had the same problem until version 1.7. Now fontspec compiles pn the cloud. I will adjust my answer to make this clear. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: fontspec is supported since Texpad macOS 1.8.5, Texpad iOS 1.8.0: https://www.texpad.com/support/generic/texpadtex/texpadtex-support

Comment: @intagli According to the release notes, that is not the case: "TexpadTeX does not support all documents quite yet, for instance, we are still working on fontspec and hyperref. " https://www.texpad.com/news/texpad-macos-1.8.0. Nonetheless, I'll try it myself and report back.

Comment: @Jonathan You linked to the 1.8.0 release, fontspec should be supported from version 1.8.5. I am using Texpad 1.8.14 and it works with the fontspec package :)

Comment: @intagli I only referenced the version of iOS that you referenced (1.8.0) in your first comment. Anyway, I see that there is a 1.8.5 version for iOS/ipadOS, and I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That‘s awesome :-) thanks for updating your answer

Comment: fontspec support for texpadtex is incomplete and weird. For example you can't even get bold and italic fonts without setting `BoldFont` and `ItalicFont` during `\setmainfont`, which is not the case for fontspec on other xetex and luatex. Also, small caps support is broken on texpadtex.